# Why only one method name is printed after calling Delegate.GetInvokationList in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, delegates

I have a query about the `Delegate.Target` property.

I defined the delegate type **BinaryOp**:

```
    public delegate int BinaryOp(int x, int y);
```

Then I created two distinct classes to provide methods to the delegate.

```
    public class SimpleMath
    {
        public int Add(int x, int y) => x + y;

        public int Subtract(int x, int y) => x - y;
    }

    public class SimpleDivision
    {
        public int Divide(int x, int y) => x / y;
    }
```

Now I am adding each one of these methods to the `allThree` instance and calling `GetInvocationList()` to **check the** `Target` **of each** `Method` in the delegate:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleMath s = new SimpleMath();
            SimpleDivision d = new SimpleDivision();

            BinaryOp add = s.Add;
            BinaryOp subtract = s.Subtract;
            BinaryOp division = d.Divide;

            BinaryOp allThree = division + add + subtract;

            DisplayDelegateInfo(allThree);
        }

        static void DisplayDelegateInfo(Delegate d)
        {
            foreach (Delegate member in d.GetInvocationList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Method name: {d.Method}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Type name: {d.Target}");
            }
        }
```

From the output seen below **only the method** `Subtract` **is printed**. 
Why is that?

Output:

```
Method name: Int32 Subtract(Int32, Int32)
Type name: Delegates.SimpleMath
Method name: Int32 Subtract(Int32, Int32)
Type name: Delegates.SimpleMath
Method name: Int32 Subtract(Int32, Int32)
Type name: Delegates.SimpleMath
```

Comment: Because you should use `member.Method` instead of `d.Method`.

Comment: Oh my sweet lord... thanks

Comment: Yes, sometimes such things are tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling Console.WriteLine on d, not your iteration variable member. Your delegate d is a chained delegate and returns the last delegate assigned to it, namely Subtract.

```
 static void DisplayDelegateInfo(Delegate d)
        {
            foreach (Delegate member in d.GetInvocationList())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Method name: {member.Method}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Type name: {member.Target}");               
            }
        }
```